# ARM GNU GCC trying to zero out the .bss section

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, elf, segments

I am having a problem,

ARM GNU GCC is trying to 'zero' the .bss section , I dont want it to do it as my startup code is doing it already. Due to this the final image size is increased by the bss size filled with zero's .

I am already using `NOLOAD` in the linker script for bss section and `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss` as part of CFLAGS for gcc.

How do I tell ARM GNU GCC not to zero out that section ?Am I missing something?

Comment: find and replace the bootstrap code with your own, and/or just let the existing bootstrap code zero bss (and copy .data, etc).

Comment: I use -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding and create my own C bootstrap code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer directly from ARM: [How to prevent uninitialized data from being initialized to zero](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472h/BABBEAEH.html)

> You can prevent uninitialized data from being initialized to zero by placing that data in a different section. This can be achieved using #pragma arm section, or with the GNU compiler extension **attribute**((section("name"))).

```
#pragma arm section zidata = “non_initialized”
int i, j; // uninitialized data in non_initialized section (without the pragma, would be in .bss section by default)
#pragma arm section zidata // back to default (.bss section)
int k = 0, l = 0; // zero-initialized data in .bss section
```